# Python function won't fully execute

Tags: python, logic

This is a dummy class to test a multiprocess generator. It takes a queue to pass a message, and a number indicating the number of times the thread has been called. 
For some reason I cant get the first print in the while loop to execute `print ("Thread type 1 number %d run count %d") % (thread_number, count)` wont run but`print ("Killing thread type 1 number %d") % thread_number` does run.

```
class test_imports:#Test classes remove 
      def import_1(self, control_queue, thread_number):
          print ("Import_1 number %d started") % thread_number# Does run
          run = True
          count = 1
          while run == True:
                alive = control_queue.get()
                print ("Thread type 1 number %d run count %d") % (thread_number, count) #wont run
                count = count + 1
                if alive == 't1kill':
                   print ("Killing thread type 1 number %d") % thread_number # does run 
                   run = False
                   break
```

Here is the completed code

```
import multiprocessing 
import time 

class test_imports:#Test classes remove 
      def import_1(self, control_queue, thread_number):
          print ("Import_1 number %d started") % thread_number
          run = True
          count = 1
          while run == True:
                alive = control_queue.get()
                print ("Thread type 1 number %d run count %d") % (thread_number, count)
                count = count + 1
                if alive == 't1kill':
                   print ("Killing thread type 1 number %d") % thread_number
                   run = False
                   break



      def import_2(self, control_queue, thread_number):
          print ("Import_2 number %d started") % thread_number
          run = True
          count = 1
          while run == True:
                alive = control_queue.get()
                print ("Thread type 2 number %d run count %d") % (thread_number, count)           
                count = count + 1
                if alive == 't2kill':
                   print ("Killing thread type 2 number %d") % thread_number
                   run = False
                   break


class worker_manager:
     def __init__(self):
        self.children = {}

     def generate(self, control_queue, threadName, runNum):
        i = test_imports()
        if threadName == 'one':
            print ("Starting import_1 number %d") % runNum
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=i.import_1, args=(control_queue, runNum))
            self.children[threadName] = p
            p.start()        
        elif threadName == 'two': 
            print ("Starting import_2 number %d") % runNum
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=i.import_2, args=(control_queue, runNum))
            self.children[threadName] = p
            p.start()
        elif threadName == 'three':    
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=i.import_1, args=(control_queue, runNum))
            print ("Starting import_1 number %d") % runNum
            p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=i.import_2, args=(control_queue, runNum))
            print ("Starting import_2 number %d") % runNum
            self.children[threadName] = p
            self.children[threadName] = p2
            p.start()
            p2.start()

        else:
            print ("Not a valid choice choose one two or three")     

     def terminate(self, threadName):
         self.children[threadName].join


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Establish communication queues
    control = multiprocessing.Queue()
    manager = worker_manager()

    runNum = int(raw_input("Enter a number: ")) 
    threadNum = int(raw_input("Enter number of threads: "))
    threadName = raw_input("Enter number: ")
    thread_Count = 0

    print ("Starting threads") 

    for i in range(threadNum):
        manager.generate(control, threadName, i)
        thread_Count = thread_Count + 1              

    time.sleep(runNum)#let threads do their thing

    print ("Terminating threads")     

    for i in range(thread_Count):
        control.put("t1kill")
        control.put("t2kill")

    manager.terminate(threadName)
```

Comment: Post the rest of your code.

Comment: It must be that control_queue.get() never returns, could that be it?  Did you step through with the debugger?

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that control_queue is empty, so it blocks waiting for a producer to add something to it.  Also, that `run = True; while run == True` bit hurts to look at.  You don't even end up _using_ the flag you're twiddling.  Just use `while True` and `break`.

Comment: @CodieCodeMonkey But if control_queue.get() didn't return, wouldn't the third print also never appear?

Comment: @CharlesMarsh, right, didn't catch that point.  Hmmm.  Looks impossible!  Still, did you step through with a debugger?

Comment: @CharlesMarsh since the OP has reported something that simply can't happen, we're ignoring it since he's clearly misinterpreting something.  Either there is a duplicate print coming from another thread or something along those lines.

Comment: Fair enough! And agreed. @KyleSponsable please post more information.

Comment: Rodger that gentlemen give me a few to get it formatted. 

@roippi I just did that because I was trying to avoid any issues that might occur by stating everything